# How do I make sure submodule is cloned, and clone it if it isn't?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have an application with a submodule (ahh). I'm trying to write a build script that makes sure it is cloned.

I don't need the submodule to update. I just need it to get cloned (if it isn't already).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
git submodule update --init
```

This command does not alter existing information in .git/config and checks out submodules to registered versions.

See also [git submodule documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule)